# How to filter specific URLs from Rails' log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I filter specific URLs from appearing in Rails logs in Development environment.

For example, I do not want this to appear in my development log:

```
Started GET "/uploads/photos/1/image.jpg" for ::1 at 2016-12-13 14:36:42 -0500
DEBUG: Chewy strategies stack: [2] <- atomic @ /Users/kalyanmaddu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chewy-0.8.4/lib/chewy/railtie.rb:17
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/photos/1/image.jpg"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317)
...
```

I am on Rails 4.2.6.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and its included links, along with "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. We'd like to know what you tried and what problem you had. If you didn't try, why not? As is, it looks like you want us to solve the problem for you or recommend tools, both of which are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

[Quiet Assets Gem](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets)